# Suppose $C$ is the unit circle in the plane and $f:C\to C$ is a map not homotopic to the identity, then $f(x)=-x$ for some $x\in C$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This from "Basic Topology" by Armstrong. I can't figure out what $f(x)=-x$ is doing when mapping from unit circles. Is this the antipodal map?

Comment: the map $x\mapsto-x$ is the antipode map. However the question asks you to show that there exists SOME $x\in C$ that is taken to its antipode via $f$ when $f$ is not homotopic to identity. It doesn't ask you to show that $f$ is the antipode map.

Comment: @Rise thank you, actually $f$ is not the antipodal map because the antipodal map is homtopic to the identity here. Can you provide some more ideas?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The unit circle is $C = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ |z|= 1\}$, a group. There exists a homotopy from identity map of $C \backslash\{-1\}$ to the constant $1$ map  $(e^{i \theta} , t) \mapsto e^{i t \theta}$ for $\theta \in ( -\pi, \pi)$ and $t \in [0,1]$.

Assume now that $f\colon C \to C$ does not take any point to its opposite. Then the map $\frac{f}{Id}$ takes $C$ to $C \backslash \{-1\}$ so, by the above, it is homotopic to the constant $1$ map. Therefore, $f = Id \cdot \frac{f}{Id}$ is homotopic to $Id \cdot 1 = Id$ map.

$\bf{Added:}$ We can prove similarly that any two maps from any space  $f, g\colon X \to S$ to an $m$ dimensional sphere $S$ (say $m \ge 1$)  such that $f(x) \ne - g(x)$ for all $x \in X$ are homotopic. Indeed, recall that we have a retraction from $r\colon D\backslash\{0\}$ to $S$. Then the following provides a homotopy between $f$ and $g$:

$$F(t, x) = r( (1-t)f(x) + t g(x))$$
with $t\in [0,1]$ and $x\in X$.

Comment: Looks great thanks, but can you please explain why we are looking at $C\backslash\{-1\}$? And how do I know there exists a homotopy between $C\backslash\{-1\}$ and the constant map?

Comment: @grayQuant A circle minus any point is just an open interval, so contractible. You look at $C \setminus \{-1\}$ because if $f$ does not map any $x$ to $-x$, then $\frac{f}{Id}$ never assumes the value $-1$